# HTML through PHP not taking a CSS rule

Tags: php, html, css

Is there any reason that the following code and syle wouldn't work? The only problem is that I can't get the text to change color, it stays black, which would be fine but the background color is black. I know it's there because I can highlight the text with the cursor and it's there in the table. Here's my code fragment.

This is from the index.php page.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr id= &quot;Data'&quot; class='&quot;Data'&quot;>";
    echo "<td id= &quot; cell &quot;>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id= &quot; cell &quot;>" . $row['Subject'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id= &quot; cell &quot;>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id= &quot; cell &quot;>" . $row['Source'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id= &quot; cell &quot;>" . $row['Comment'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

here's the css rule that SHOULD be applied.....but isn't.

`#Cell{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: white;`

Comment: What does this have to do with hostnames or MySQL. Show us the outputted HTML, not the code used to create it.

Comment: Your markup is invalid.  `id` should be unique in the DOM, but you have multiple elements with the same `id`.  With invalid markup the behavior is pretty much undefined, so you take your chances.

Comment: Was asking myself the same thing.

Comment: Use classes not id for repeating elements. IDs should be unique.

Comment: what does this have to do with hostnames?

Comment: Pretty sure &quot; won't be converted to a ". You have to escape it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<td id= &quot; cell &quot;>` is not equivalent to `<td id="cell">` because HTML does not recursively evaluate itself. So the former tag is invalid gobbledegook without an id. You also cannot give the same id to more than one element.

Comment: ok so I replaced it as a class, same problem. If I can't use `&quot` then how do I avoid having the PHP think that I am ending the statement when in fact I'm trying to nest HTML?

Comment: @user2050069 Use `echo "<td class=\"cell\">"` I'm not sure how he got 5 upvotes without mentioning that. Alternatively, most seem to prefer closing the interpreter as opposed to echo. It would look like this `<? while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ ?> <tr class="Data"><td class="cell"><?=$row['Name']?></td></tr><?}?>` No need for escape tags or echo.

Comment: @user `'<td class="...">'`

Comment: @Oberon <?php=...?> can be used above PHP ver 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Why your are using `&quot; cell &quot;`

Here is correct code

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr id=\"Data\" class=\"Data\">";
    echo "<td id=\"cell\">" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id=\"cell\">" . $row['Subject'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id=\"cell\">" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id=\"cell\">" . $row['Source'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td id=\"cell\">" . $row['Comment'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that "correct" code since it produces invalid HTML.

Comment: it is valid HTML " has been escaped with \ and thats what required, also you can use ' (single quote) instead of " (double code)

Comment: That makes it valid PHP, not valid HTML.  You're using the same `id` on multiple elements, which is invalid.